# Eval-ing paramaters in Elixir (with Ecto)

Tags: elixir, ecto

Have a look at the `select()` line below:

```
def query_group(user, group_by, filters \\[]) do
    from(Click)
    |> select([c], {c.^group_by, count(c)})
    |> where([c], c.link_user_id == ^user.id)
    |> where([c], ^filters)
    |> group_by([c], ^group_by)
    |> Repo.all
    |> Enum.map(&(Tuple.to_list &1))
  end
```

`group_by` is an atom. For example, if `group_by = :platform`, then in the `select` field, I need to get `select([c], {c.platform, count(c)})`.

What's the best way of approaching this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `field/2`, as in `select([c], {field(c, ^group_by), count(1)})`
(not sure `group_by` needs to be pinned here but I think so)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fragments](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#join/5-joining-with-fragments) for this, changing the select bit to

```
...
|> select(fragment("count(*), ?", ^group_by))
```

This way you can use the input of the function easily.